# Update an App Service Certificate with Azure Management SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

I'd like to build an application capable uploading a new certificate, deleting old TLS bindings, and creating a new TLS binding for App Service sites.

I am using the Azure Management SDK (Azure ResourceManager) v1.1 but I have not found a way to get/update private site certificates.

Is this possible using the .NET Azure Management SDK?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible using the .NET Azure Management SDK?

AFAIK, it is not possible to update private site certificates to Azure App Service by using .NET Azure Management SDK.

Generally creating, provisioning, and managing Azure resources from within .NET applications is possible with the help of the Resource management using the Azure SDK for .NET. There are management libraries for each Azure service.

Alternatively, we can upload/import a private certificate or a public certificate into Azure App Service by using the below documentation.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex,portal) clearly states the options available for adding certificates in App Service.

And also check this post given by `@SnehaAgarwal-MSFT` -
[For self-renewing certificate for an Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/560204/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-self-renewing-certifica.html).